# Where should platform-dependent header files be installed?

Tags: c

For example, if a header defines something based on configure checks which depend on the platform (e.g. different for x86 and x86-64), where should it be installed?

Comment: Do you want to write an header file ? . Platform dependent code is usually written in header files .You can write the platform dependent code as an ifdef statements in the header file and include the same in the code.

Comment: It's generated by a configure script.

Answer (score 1):

You don't install header files.

You can place them wherever you want.  In your install script, your conditional will just point to the appropriate files when taking the correct branch.  You can put any file path you want in these conditionals.

Comment: Plus your configure script will allow a `--prefix` argument, allowing a user chosen installation path.